# MongoDB: reducing examined:returned ratio when using $text and $search

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, indexing

I'm using Mongo Atlas and I receive quite a few warnings about a high **examined:returned** ratio. Upon inspection the queries in question are using `$text` indexes and the `$search` feature.

See the query below:

```
{
  "find": "users",
  "filter": {
    "role": "USER",
    "$text": {
      "$search": "someone@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "score": {
      "$meta": "textScore"
    }
  },
  "projection": {
    "score": {
      "$meta": "textScore"
    }
  },
  "limit": 20,
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to fix this high ratio? I have an index for `role` already and obviously it's using my `text` index.

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Add explained query plans to question.

Comment: @D.SM sorry I don't understand what you mean?>

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/